# C# Enums with string properties

Tags: c#, string, properties, enums

Let's say I have enum with some strings in it like this:

```
enum MyEnum
    {
        stringA = "String a",
        stringB = "String b"
    }
```

Then, I try to access a string property of a string in this enum:

```
MyEnum.stringA.Length
```

And it doesn't let me. I can't use any of the string properties with the strings in the enum. Is it possible to access these string properties? or am I doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a class. you  can not do that with enums.

Comment: You are not allowed to declare enums with string values.

Comment: _"Let's say I have enum with some strings in it like this"_ - let's say you [try to compile that, and that only](http://ideone.com/dRxJrK). You see it won't work, so you can forget any  string operation after that. Explain _why_ you want to assign a string value to an enum member, and perhaps there's a different way to do that.

Comment: `class MyClass
    {
        public static string stringA = "String a";

        public static string stringB = "String b";
    }` and then use `MyClass.stringA.Length`

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this enum? Enum values are integers, and are normally used to define a set of related constants.

Comment: First get a working enum, *then* try to use it.

Comment: @NikolayKostov: Ick, no - those are public, writable instance fields. Either `const` or `public static readonly`...

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `DescriptionAttribute` from the `System.ComponentModel` namespace.

```
enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("String a")]
    stringA,
    [Description("String b")]
    stringB
}
```

And then use this method to get description:

```
public static string GetDescription(Enum Enumeration)
{
     string Value = Enumeration.ToString();
     Type EnumType = Enumeration.GetType();
     var DescAttribute = (DescriptionAttribute[])EnumType
            .GetField(Value)
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
     return DescAttribute.Length > 0 ? DescAttribute[0].Description : Value;
}
```

And you can get the value:

```
var result = GetDescription(MyEnum.stringA).Length;
```

Comment: You can do that, but depending on what OP wants to do it may or may not be the proper solution.

Comment: @CodeCaster I totally agree with your comment here and in the question. But, OP didn't explain us why he or she needs that. And I thought that my answer could help OP.